# How to run a function when a subprocess is terminated?

Tags: python, subprocess, atexit

I have 2 python codes, one of which is mar.py and the other is sub.py

```
## mar.py
import os
import subprocess
import time

print('MASTER PID: ', os.getpid())

proc = subprocess.Popen(["D:\Miniconda3\python.exe", r"C:\Users\J\Desktop\test\sub.py"], shell=False)

def terminator():
    proc.terminate()

time.sleep(5)
terminator()
```

`mar.py` simply creates a subprocess using `sub.py` and terminates it in 5 seconds.

```
## sub.py
import atexit
import time
import os

print('SUB PID: ', os.getpid())

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\J\\Desktop\\test")

def handle_exit():
    with open("foo.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("Life is too short, you need python")

atexit.register(handle_exit)

while True:
    print('alive')
    time.sleep(1)
```

I thought `foo.txt` would be created before the subprocess of `sub.py` is terminated, but nothing happens. If I run `sub.py` on its own and terminate it, it creates `foo.txt` as I planned. What does make this difference and how could I still make it create `foo.txt` even when it's run as a subprocess?

I'm using Windows 10(64bit) and Python 3.6.5 (32bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say you "terminate" sub.py, does this mean you press Ctrl+C on it? On windows, this actually sends `CTRL_C_EVENT` to the process, unlike `terminate()` method which calls `TerminateProcess` WinAPI method.

Looks like you need to `import signal` and then do `proc.send_signal(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)` instead of `proc.terminate()`

Comment: Yes, I pressed Ctrl+C on it. Thank you so much for the answer! It works now!